# Ampersand in Windows Password

Tags: windows, batch-file, perforce

I have a password for a Perforce account which contains an ampersand (&) and when I try to use certain P4 commands, I get the following error:

```
Perforce password (P4PASSWD) invalid or unset.
```

I have a feeling it has something to do with the ampersand causing the password to not be recognized in the Windows command shell, however I am more familiar with bash than with Windows, so I'm not sure how to handle this. Any Windows experts out there that have seen something like this? I'd like to avoid having to change the password if possible but somehow set my P4PASSWD environment variable such that it is recognized by the shell as the correct password.

Comment: Why are you against changing the password?  Why go against the current on something like this?

Comment: A password in a environment var? I hope you realize that you are storing it in plain-text and ANY application can read it. That even goes as far as exposing it to any web-sites you are visiting from that computer.

Comment: Isn't P4PASSWD an environment var though? Why else would it complain when I run something like this:

`p4 changes -s submitted -m1`
`Perforce password (P4PASSWD) invalid or unset.`

Comment: @Tonny: How _exactly_ do websites get access to your environment variables?

Comment: @Tonny: I don't see how the latter method could possibly work. Windows does not _in any way_ magically rewrite HTTP request URLs within browsers unless the browser itself explicitly calls some sort of variable-expansion function. And if it did so, that would break every single address that has a series of URL-encoded special characters (%20 and such).

Comment: @grawity ActiveX is one method. (IE specific obviously.) The other works through specially crafted redirect URLs like "http://bad.website.com/redirect.asp&expose_%ENVVAR%.htm". The browsers expands ENVVAR before sending the new URL back to the server. Server can then get the content. Some old IE versions used to do this. I just verified that Firefox V31 and Internet Explorer 11 are not susceptible to this.

Comment: @grawity Just did another test: IE11 will expand %VAR% but the var must exist. If it doesn't (like %20%20) it will leave it alone.

Answer (score 4):

You are correct. The ampersand is a special character in the windows command line. Typically to escape it you use the caret (^), or double quotes. If neither of those work (or if you aren't actually typing your password on the command line) I would suggest just changing your password.

For example:

```
C:\Windows\System32>echo a&b
a
'b' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Windows\System32>echo a^&b
a&b

C:\Windows\System32>
```

Comment: The `^` is a *caret*. [This](http://i.stack.imgur.com/LlQIg.jpg) is a *carrot*. Sorry, couldn't resist.

Comment: @Bob Hehe. Thx, it's fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Reference [Syntax : Escape Characters, Delimiters and Quotes](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html)

> **^  Escape character.**
>
> Adding the escape character before a command symbol allows it to be
>   treated as ordinary text. When [piping or redirecting](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) any of these
>   characters you should prefix with the escape character: & \ < > ^ |
>
> `^\  ^&  ^|  ^>  ^<  ^^`

So in the Windows command shell you need to use `^&` instead of `&` to escape the special meaning of `&`